# how to get the userID of logged in user in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

for example i've posted an apartment (our system is about renting an apartment) i want to get the userID of the current logged in so that after apartment posted the userID will be now the owner of the apartment
Here's my code: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Vol.png)

Comment: images of code are not acceptable; post your real code. Your question is also too broad.

Comment: $name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$bedrooms = $_POST['numofbedrooms'];
$descrip = $_POST['description'];
$amenities = $_POST['amenities'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$apartmentName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `apartment`( `user_id`,`apartmentName`, `address`, `no_of_bedrooms`, `description`, `amenities`, `price`, `status`) VALUES ('{$apartmentName}', '{$address}', '$bedrooms', '{$descrip}', '{$amenities}', {$price}, 'Available')";
$data = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);

Comment: you need to edit https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44217032/edit your question and not drop code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking here. But:

```
 $user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

should do it for you